# Structural types in Dotty/Scala 3 compiled failed?

Tags: scala, structural-typing, dotty, scala-3

I tested the following code of structural type:

```
trait Data

object Main
{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    val data = new Data {
      val value: Int = 1
    }

    println(data.value)
  }
}
```

It compiled successfully in Scala 2.13.2 but failed in Dotty/Scala3. How to use structural types in Dotty/Scala3? Thanks!

Comment: http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/structural-types.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I see:

- inference changed, so you have to refine type explicitly:

  ```
  val data: Data { val value: Int } = new Data {
    val value: Int = 1
  }
  ```

  You can see it clearly when you run `dotr` and check what is the inferred type
- to make use of refinement you have to let compiler know that you don't mind reflection

  ```
  import reflect.Selectable.reflectiveSelectable
  ```

Putting it together:

```
import reflect.Selectable.reflectiveSelectable

trait Data

object Main
{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    val data: Data { val value: Int } = new Data {
      val value: Int = 1
    }

    println(data.value)
  }
}
```

I guess the reason why you have to do this is because many times when one didn't want to have refinement, one had it (e.g test all test fixtures `new Fixture { ... }` were refined types unnecessarily). The other is that refinements use reflection when accessing refinements (in Scala 2) which causes performance penalty - so it is something we should do consciously and not accidentally.

In Scala 3, structural types are implemented using [dynamics](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/structural-types-spec.html), which require mixing in `Selectable` trait. Because of that you would have to import `scala.reflect.Selectable.reflectiveSelectable` implicit conversion to allow it to work like in Scala 2. If you want to make things work like before you can add `import reflect.Selectable.{ given _ }` as suggested by @Dmytro Mitin (and add reflection back).

You can try to do it globally e.g. by [exporting](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/export.html) it in your package, but it you would do it on your own risk.

Comment: Import also can be written as `import reflect.Selectable.{ given _ }`.

Comment: Actually I think old-style structural typing is useful for using Scala more like a 'dynamic' language without declaring types explicitly while keeping static type checking. New-style structural typing is much tedious in writing types. I really hope Scala 3 keep old-style structural typing available. Is it possible?